# dispatch actions in storeon with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'am writing my browser extension and trying to add storeon to my code. 
And I don't know how to correct write actions in dispatch;
For expample I want to dispatch this function:

```
getTimeEntryInProgress() {
    let userId = this.localStorageService.get("userId");
    this.timeEntryService
      .list(userId)
      .then(response => {
        let timeEntry = response.data.filter(
          x =>
            x.custom_fields[0].value === "false" ||
            x.custom_fields[0].value === "0"
        )[0];
        this.setTimeEntryInProgress(timeEntry);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.application.setIcon(IconStatus.TimeEntryEnded);
      });
  }
```

Also for example this is one of my store module :

```
export const timeEntryModule: Module<TimeEntryState, TimeEntryEvents> = store => {
    store.on('@init', () => ({
        timeEntries: [],
        selectedTimeEntry: null,
        timeEntryInProgress: null
    }));
    store.on('timeEntry/select', (state, selectedTimeEntry) => ({ selectedTimeEntry }));
    store.on('timeEntry/inProgress', (state, timeEntryInProgress) => ({ timeEntryInProgress }));
}
```

May be some one could help or give a useful link?